# Decode values of a tuple in django template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

```
  if(len(f1) > 0):  
    for qs in profile_map:
        p = Profile.objects.get(pk=qs.emp.id)
        t_name = p.first_name + p.last_name
        t_arr.append((q.profile.id,emp_name))
    response_dictionary.update({'tarr':t_arr})
  render_to_response('project/profile_table.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'response_dictionary': response_dictionary}))
```

In Django template How to deocode all the 1.values of the tuple 2.search the tuple for a certain value in q.profile.id

```
        {% for ele in response_dictionary.tarr%}
            alert('{{ele}}');
        //Get this as alert (11L, u&#39;Employee3.&#39;)
         {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the generator will assign the tuple to `ele`, so you can access the first, last name with `{{ ele.0 }} {{ ele.1 }}`.

But this is also legal, to unpack the tuple into two vars:

```
{% for first_name, last_name in response_dictionary.tarr %}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using django 0.96 you can't have multiple values in for loop. so this will not work:

```
{% for first_name, last_name in response_dictionary.tarr %}
```

instead use

```
{% for ele in response_dictionary.tarr %}
     {{ ele.0 }} {{ ele.1 }}
{% endfor %}
```